# All uniform locations are "-1" on MacOS X

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, after-effects

I am experiencing really  weird bug.I am porting some OpenGL codebase to MacOS X 10.7.5 The OpenGL code is suited for GL3.2 version.Original version (on Windows/Linux") works fine.No errors in GLSL or OpenGL side.But on Mac, when trying to access the uniforms all the locations are "-1".It is problematic to put out here the whole code as it is wrapped into framework(also I am sure 100% it is written correctly as it was tested to great extent on other platforms),but here is some of GLSL code:

```
#version 150 core
uniform sampler2D tex;  
uniform vec2 dir;  
uniform float cont;
noperspective in vec2 uv;
out vec4 colorOut;  
void main(){
...
```

All the uniforms are in use by the shader so it is unlikely that GLSLcompiler optimizes them out.

**UPDATE:**

Ok,I have some advance in pinning down the problem.Somehow, it seems that the character string, I pass to a method which retrieves uniform location,gets truncated.Here is the test:

Explicit call to :

```
GLuint loc1 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderEmboss->getHandle(), "dir");
```

returns the location al right.

But if I pass the location name as param "const GLchar* name" , I can see in the XCode debugger only the first char of the string.

Comment: Regarding the update: strcmp() evaluates to 0 (false) if the strings are equal.

Comment: Did you request a 3.2 rendering context from the OS? 

Check with glGetIntegerv( GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major ); and glGetIntegerv( GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor );

Comment: @umlum  Oops! .Yes, 3.2 core is requested and it is up as the shader program gets compiled and linked ok.But why then I am getting valid location when passing the name string directly?

Comment: That it works correctly on other platforms does not mean that your code is correct, it also could be that you e.g. the driver/card is less strict about the code (I often have seen that the driver of OS X in core 3.2 is more strict then e.g. NVIDIA drivers on Windows) Did you check the output of `glGetShaderInfoLog` and `glGetProgramInfoLog`? And did you check if the final program is valid with `glValidateProgram`?

Comment: Yep,you are right man.Here is what the validation throws:"current draw framebuffer is invalid".Why?I do create custom FBO at later stage during rendering, but how is it connected to program validation?

Comment: IfI validate after FBO bound it passes ok.So the program is valid.

Comment: The _problem_ with OpenGL and its drivers is that once an error occurred your context is (could be) - improperly said - in an undefined state. So if your program fails at one point does not mean that the error necessarily occurred there. The - what i think - best way to avoid such problems is to check EVERY _gl*_ statement with an `glGetError` (and additional error infos like `glGetShaderInfoLog`, `glGetProgramInfoLog`, ...) afterwards using an assert that you could control with a flag (so that you are able to let it be optimized out by to compiler in production code)

Comment: Checked with glError all the way.There are none.

Comment: @MichaelIV so also `glGetUniformLocation` does not give you a `glGetError` ? Could you check how many active uniform you have with  `glGetProgramiv(m_program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, &count);` and show their info if you have active ones with `glGetActiveUniform`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37012/discussion-between-t-niese-and-michael-iv)

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to @umlum for debug help.I managed to pin down the issue.It has to do with multiple OpenGL context.My program is plugin in Adobe AfterEffect(AE).AE during runtime spawns its own contexts at will.In my code each time I render OpenGL stuff I was enabling my context like this (MaxOS X):

```
   _context = CGLGetCurrentContext() ;
    CGLSetCurrentContext(_context);
```

Calling the first line appeared to be grave mistake!What happens (probably) is that at the time I am trying to access the (supposedly  mine)  current context, it is already not my context but one of AE contexts which the program manages independently. 
_context = CGLGetCurrentContext() - I commented this line and it seems to be working now.
I figured it all out by using

```
glGetActiveUniform()
```

Running it I found that my shader program contains uniform names which it doesn't really have.So it became apparent that my program's handle probably references a program from different context.